# C socket issue with read/write for loops

Tags: c, sockets

I am creating a chat application where two programs (chat serve and chat client) send messages back and forth.
I am trying to set it up to send one char at a time. I calculate how long the message should be and send that number from chat serve to chat client. The number transfer with no problem but when I try to read/write a message it is successfully sent with the print statements indicating the for loop should end however after the last letter is sent the program just hangs. With the print message for message succesffully sent/received never being triggered. However if Sig INT chat client while they are both hanging chat serve seems to finish its write and it displays finished sending message. I am at a bit of loss for what is going on. From my print statements it looks like the for loops should have their conditions met but the programs both seem to get stuck in them.

Chat Serve: 
Above the code shown I hardcode in "Tom:" as hosthandle and take user input for hostmessage which in this case I am putting as test. mone is

```
char mone[2]="";

//send message to chatclient
charcount= strlen(hostmessage);
meslen=charcount+strlen(hosthandle);//total message length
int number_to_send = meslen; 
int converted_number = htonl(number_to_send);
write(newsockfd, &converted_number, sizeof(converted_number)); //sends number to chat client
for (j=0;j<strlen(hosthandle);j++)
{
    mone[0]=hosthandle[j];
    n = write(newsockfd, mone, 2); //writes handle to chatclient
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        perror("Message not \n");
    }
    printf("%s  %d \n",mone, j);
}
for (j=0;j<strlen(hostmessage);j++)
{
    mone[0]=hostmessage[j];
    n = write(newsockfd, mone, 2); //writes message to chatclient  
    printf("%s  %d \n",mone, j);
}
printf("Finished Sending Message");
```

Output of program (hostmessage is test message size=8)

Transcript:

```
Tom: test
T  0
o  1
m  2
:  3
t  0
e  1
s  2
t  3
```

ChatClient

```
int received_int = 0; //this section of code receives message length from chatserve
int return_status = read(sockfd, &received_int, sizeof(received_int));
if (return_status > 0) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Received int = %d\n", ntohl(received_int));
    }
else 
{
    printf("did not receive message length");
}
for(j=0;j<received_int;j++)
{
    n=read(sockfd,kone,2); //reads in letter from chat serve
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        perror("Message not recieved\n");
    }
    //printf("%d \n", n);
    printf("%s   %d \n",kone, j);
}
printf("Received message \n");
```

Output of program after this it just hangs when I feel like both for loops should have hit their counter.

```
Received int = 8
T   0
o   1
m   2
:   3
t   4
e   5
s   6
t   7
```

Comment: Usuals:  failure to correctly and completely handle the result returned by read().  Calls to functions that expect null-terminated char arrays when the passed arguments are not guaranteed null-terminated.

Comment: You might encounter another problem: `for(j=0;j<strlen(hosthandle);j++)` &ndash; this will *not* include the terminating null character. How are you going to separate them?

Answer (score 1):

`mone` only contains one element, but you're writing two characters with:

```
n = write(newsockfd, mone, 2);
```

You need to declare `mone` as:

```
char mone[] = " ";
```

so that it contains one character followed by the trailing null byte. Your declaration just has the trailing null byte. Also

```
char[] mone = "";
```

is not even valid syntax, I don't understand how the program compiled.

In the client, you should also check that `read()` actually returns 2 bytes. Nothing guarantees that each call to `read()` will get everything sent in the corresponding `write()` in the sender. `read()` is allowed to return any number up to the amount you request, so it could return 1 byte at a time, and you would need to call again to get the second byte.

```
int total_needed = 2;
int total_read = 0;
while (total_read < total_needed) {
    n = read(sockfd, mone + total_read, total_needed - total_read);
    if (n < 0) {
        perror("Error while reading");
        break;
    } else if (n == 0) {
        printf("Unexpected EOF\n");
        break;
    } else {
        total_read += n;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Aconcagua True, datagram sockets preserve message boundaries.

Comment: I am sorry for invalid deceleration of char mone[]=" "; Could you show me an example of how I would check to see that read functioned properly.

Comment: @maxpearson `n` is the number of characters that were read. Use a loop that keeps reading and adding `n` to a total, until you get to the number that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I do not see why you want to write every character on its own. This only complicates your live without any benefit (visible to me at least).

If using UDP sockets, you should rather try to combine the whole message into a single UDP packet (e. g. by putting the converted int and the complete data into a single buffer and send (write) everything in one single go). If using TCP, your data will get combined to a stream anyway, without any visible borders to the client (packing the data into ip packets is done within the socket implementation).

Not sure if you have noticed, you implicitely defined a protocol already: At first you send with four bytes in network byte order the number of bytes to be followed, followed by – guess what – exactly this number of data...

If using UDP, you would have to try to get the whole message in one single read (if you provide a too small buffer, the rest of the message is discarded!). If using TCP, read not necessarily does return the complete message. So the client would do the following to implement the protocol you defined:

- Read four bytes from the stream – possibly, you need more than one call to read!
- Evaluate these four bytes to the number of expected bytes.
- Read this number of bytes from the stream – again possibly with more than one call to read.

Be aware that read can block; if you have other tasks to do, you could test with select or poll, if data is available at all and only read then (or you have multiple threads anyway).

Edit: as you asked for (hope this does not come late) – this is how I would do it:

```c
int readFromSocket(int fd, char* buffer, unsigned long length)
{
    unsigned int count = 0;
    char* b = buffer;

    while(count < length)
    {
        int n = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(length) - count);
        if(n < 0 && errno != EINTR) // EINTR: interrupted due to signal -> can continue
        {
            // handle error, possibly:
            // * closing socket (next messages might be corrupt now!)
            // * calling exit(-1), abort(), ...
            // * returning - as here - an error
            return -1;
        }
        count -= n;
        buffer += n;
    }

    return 0; // OK
}

int handleNextMessage(int fd)
{
    int result = 0;
    unsigned int length;
    char* message;
    result = readFromSocket(fd, (char*)&length, sizeof(length));
    if(result == 0)
    {
        length = htonl(length);
        // possibly check first length for valid range
        message = malloc(length);
        result = readFromSocket(fd, message, length);
        if(result == 0)
        {
            // do what ever needs to be done with message
        }
        // important, else you get a memory leak:
        free(message);
    }
    if(!result != 0)
    {
        // appropriate error handling
        // all handling proposed within readFromSocket could
        // alternatively be done here, too...
        // or outside handleNextMessage
    }
    return result;
}
```

Instead of using malloc and free, you can consider using a buffer on the stack:

```c
char message[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
```

Make sure that the server then does not send longer messages than the client can read.

One important node: If you ever fail to read the complete message, you might have read a message only partially. If you simply continue, you risk reading the rest of the previous message as begin of the next one and getting corrupt data. So you should close your socket and – if need be – re-open it.

There is one little problem left at server side: How are you going to separate the handle from the message again at client side (unless handle has a fixed length)? I recommend including the terminating 0 character (and, as using TCP, simply write all data at once):

```c
int isSuccess, result, lenHandle, lenMessage;
// ...
lenHandle = strlen(hosthandle) + 1; // +1: for terminating 0 character
lenMessage = strlen(hostmessage) + 1;
meslen = lenHandle + lenMessage;
meslen = htonl(meslen);
result = write(newsockfd, &meslen, sizeof(meslen);
isSuccess = 0;
if(result == sizeof(meslen))
{
    result = write(newsockfd, hosthandle, lenHandle);
    if(result == lenHandle)
    {
        result = write(newsockfd, hostmessage, lenMessage);
        isSuccess = result == lenHandle;
    }
}
if(!isSuccess)
{
    // handle errno appropriately
}
```

Be aware that write can also result in error with EINTR, in which case you could continue, so you could wrap each write in a loop:

```c
do
{
    result = write(/*...*/);
}
while(result < 0 && errno == EINTR);
```

Comment: I am using TCP would you mind explaing a bit more showing or example of what you mean for reading and evaluating 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will test this out tomorrow and see how it goes. If I am just printing my message that would go in the second result==0 section correct.